# Why is this a contradiction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The equation $(n + k)(n - k) = -n$, where $n>0, k>0$, is supposed to be a contradiction. What makes it a contradiction?

Comment: To which ring or field do $n$ and $k$ belong ?

Comment: Presumably, talking about integer only.

Comment: Do we know if $n>k$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can $n+k$ be a divisor of $n$?

Answer (score 4):

$$(n+k)(n-k)=-n\iff n(n+1)=k^2$$

Since $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$, we would need $n$ and $n+1$ to both be squares.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(n+k)(n-k)=-n$ implies that $n(n+1)=k^{2}$.

Assuming that we are referring to integers, this equation has solution $n=0$ or $n=-1$, which clearly do not fit the requirement $n>0$.

This result is not difficult to prove.

Assume that $a(a+1)=b^{2}$ where $a,b$ are integers.

Then,

$a=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{4b^{2}+1}}{2}$

Since $(2b)^{2}+1$ is only square if $b=0$

It follows that $a(a+1)=0$.

Hence $a=0$ or $a=-1$